Run external command in bg (other thread), capture output when available for rendering in TUI
I'm writing a little TUI in Rust using ratatui which needs to communicate with external programms, capture the output and render it.
I know the basics of running processes in other threads and send the results via mpsc::channel() or share it via Arc<Mutex<...>> structs. But in case of the TUI, I don't get it to work the way I need it.
In general, the app consists of a list in one area and the info for the selected list item in the other area. I made a little example using curl and DOI's. The DOI's represent the list. In the info area the Bibtex formatting of the selected DOI should be rendered using curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex" <doi>.
If I don't spawn the command which fetches the Bibtex info in a different thread, list movement is blocked as long as curl fetches the results, which is the normal behaviour for single-threaded apps running longer lasting tasks.
Now, I spawn another thread to run the fetch_bibtex() function in the background and capture the output if its there. Theoretically, it works, but if I move the list to fast, the rendered info is not the one of the selected item. And after a while curl quits with "too many requests" error.
What I want, but can't get to work: In case I move the list very fast, I want to only load the info of the item I stop on. This means, for fast movement running processes which didn't finish yet need to be killed. But don't know how to do that. Even I'm not sure on which event to call the fetch_bibtex() function. I tried different things, nothing worked.
Nice-to-have would be to render a "... Loading" or similar as long as the info isn't there.
Here is my minimal example which uses Arc<Mutex<String>> for the info content. I did also try to send the info if fetched and receive it with mpsc channels, but the outcome was similar:
use std::{
    process::{Command, Stdio},
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
};

use color_eyre::Result;
use crossterm::event::{self, Event, KeyCode, KeyEvent, KeyEventKind, KeyModifiers};
use ratatui::{
    layout::{Constraint, Layout},
    style::{Modifier, Style},
    widgets::{Block, List, ListState, Paragraph},
    DefaultTerminal, Frame,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct App {
    running: bool,
    info_text: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
    list: Vec<String>,
    state: ListState,
}

impl App {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            running: false,
            info_text: Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new())),
            list: vec![
                "http://dx.doi.org/10.1163/9789004524774".into(),
                "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.algal.2015.04.001".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199595006.003.0021".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-4587-2_7".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199595006.003.0022".into(),
            ],
            state: ListState::default().with_selected(Some(0)),
        }
    }

    pub fn run(mut self, mut terminal: DefaultTerminal) -> Result<()> {
        self.running = true;
        while self.running {
            terminal.draw(|frame| self.draw(frame))?;
            self.handle_crossterm_events()?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn draw(&mut self, frame: &mut Frame) {
        self.fetch_bibtex();
        let [left, right] =
            Layout::vertical([Constraint::Fill(1), Constraint::Fill(1)]).areas(frame.area());

        let list = List::new(self.list.clone())
            .block(Block::bordered().title_top("List"))
            .highlight_style(Style::new().add_modifier(Modifier::REVERSED));

        let info = Paragraph::new(self.info_text.lock().unwrap().clone().to_string())
            .block(Block::bordered().title_top("Bibtex-Style"));

        frame.render_stateful_widget(list, left, &mut self.state);
        frame.render_widget(info, right);
    }

    fn handle_crossterm_events(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        match event::read()? {
            Event::Key(key) if key.kind == KeyEventKind::Press => self.on_key_event(key),
            Event::Mouse(_) => {}
            Event::Resize(_, _) => {}
            _ => {}
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn fetch_bibtex(&mut self) {
        let sel_doi = self.list[self.state.selected().unwrap_or(0)].clone();
        let info_str = Arc::clone(&self.info_text);

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let output = Command::new("curl")
                .arg("-LH")
                .arg("Accept: application/x-bibtex")
                .arg(&sel_doi)
                .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                .output()
                .expect("Not running");

            let output_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).to_string();
            let mut info = info_str.lock().unwrap();
            *info = output_str;
        });
    }

    fn on_key_event(&mut self, key: KeyEvent) {
        match (key.modifiers, key.code) {
            (_, KeyCode::Esc | KeyCode::Char('q'))
            | (KeyModifiers::CONTROL, KeyCode::Char('c') | KeyCode::Char('C')) => self.quit(),
            (_, KeyCode::Down | KeyCode::Char('j')) => {
                if self.state.selected().unwrap() <= 3 {
                    self.state.scroll_down_by(1);
                }
            }
            (_, KeyCode::Up | KeyCode::Char('k')) => {
                self.state.scroll_up_by(1);
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    fn quit(&mut self) {
        self.running = false;
    }
}

fn main() -> color_eyre::Result<()> {
    color_eyre::install()?;
    let terminal = ratatui::init();
    let result = App::new().run(terminal);
    ratatui::restore();
    result
}

For sure, that is only an example. In the real app the list is much longer. Also curl and Bibtex code are only dummy examples since they should be available on most UNIX systems. The programm I use in my real app is not that wide spread, therefore, I choosed curl as example because of the time delay it has fetching Bibtex keys.
Unfortunately, using a native Rust lib or a C-lib with a well-programmed API which I can connect to through Rust is not possible, since no such lib exists for the programm I'm trying to run as background process.
I appreciate every help what I need to change. I only started learning Rust a few months ago and have no professionell programming background yet. So mistakes like this are opportunities to learn!
Edit: Close to goal
I've reworked everything a little bit and have almost the result I'm looking for. By inserting a delay using event::poll it only fetches the current items info if I stay on the item for about 500ms. So if I move the list fast, I don't run too many bg processes.
Only thing still not perfect: If I move the list constantly but not too fast, so the bg-processes are triggered every time, it still fetches the infos from the last item and draws it for a short time before it draws the current items info. Thus, I need to kill all "old" processes which are still running in the bg on every keypress which selects a new item. So far, I tried many things (bools, AtomicBools etc) but couldn't figure out how to do that since the bg thread is blocked as long as curl runs...
Happy for last hints!
use std::{
    process::{Command, Stdio},
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        mpsc::{self, channel, Receiver, Sender},
        Arc, Condvar, Mutex,
    },
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

use color_eyre::Result;
use crossterm::event::{self, Event, KeyCode, KeyEvent, KeyEventKind, KeyModifiers};
use ratatui::{
    layout::{Constraint, Layout},
    style::{Modifier, Style},
    widgets::{Block, List, ListState, Paragraph},
    DefaultTerminal, Frame,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Mailbox {
    finished: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    data: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>>,
    cond: Arc<Condvar>,
    output: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
}

impl Mailbox {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            finished: Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
            data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None)),
            cond: Arc::new(Condvar::new()),
            output: Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new())),
        }
    }
}

pub fn run_bg_cmd(
    data: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>>,
    cond: Arc<Condvar>,
    output_field: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
    finished: Arc<AtomicBool>,
) {
    loop {
        let mut guard = data.lock().unwrap();
        while guard.is_none() {
            guard = cond.wait(guard).unwrap();
        }
        let request = guard.take().unwrap();

        drop(guard);

        let output = Command::new("curl")
            .arg("-LH")
            .arg("Accept: application/x-bibtex")
            .arg(&request)
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .stderr(Stdio::null())
            .output()
            .expect("Not running");

        if output.status.success() {
            finished.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
            let output_str = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).to_string();

            let mut output_mut = output_field.lock().unwrap();
            *output_mut = output_str;
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct App {
    mb: Mailbox,
    running: bool,
    fetch_info: bool,
    info_text: String,
    list: Vec<String>,
    state: ListState,
}

impl App {
    pub fn new(mb: Mailbox) -> Self {
        Self {
            mb,
            running: false,
            fetch_info: false,
            info_text: String::new(),
            list: vec![
                "http://dx.doi.org/10.1163/9789004524774".into(),
                "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.algal.2015.04.001".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199595006.003.0021".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-4587-2_7".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199595006.003.0022".into(),
            ],
            state: ListState::default().with_selected(Some(0)),
        }
    }

    pub fn run(mut self, mut terminal: DefaultTerminal) -> Result<()> {
        self.running = true;
        while self.running {
            terminal.draw(|frame| self.draw(frame))?;
            self.handle_crossterm_events()?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn draw(&mut self, frame: &mut Frame) {
        let [left, right] =
            Layout::vertical([Constraint::Fill(1), Constraint::Fill(1)]).areas(frame.area());

        let list = List::new(self.list.clone())
            .block(Block::bordered().title_top("List"))
            .highlight_style(Style::new().add_modifier(Modifier::REVERSED));

        let info = Paragraph::new(self.info_text.as_str())
            .block(Block::bordered().title_top("Bibtex-Style"));

        frame.render_stateful_widget(list, left, &mut self.state);
        frame.render_widget(info, right);
    }

    fn handle_crossterm_events(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        if event::poll(Duration::from_millis(500))? {
            match event::read()? {
                Event::Key(key) if key.kind == KeyEventKind::Press => self.on_key_event(key),
                Event::Mouse(_) => {}
                Event::Resize(_, _) => {}
                _ => {}
            }
        } else {
            if self.fetch_info {
                self.update_info();
            }
            if self.mb.finished.load(Ordering::Relaxed) == true {
                self.info_text = self.mb.output.lock().unwrap().to_string();
                self.mb.finished.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn update_info(&mut self) {
        let sel_doi = self.list[self.state.selected().unwrap_or(0)].clone();
        let mut guard = self.mb.data.lock().unwrap();
        *guard = Some(sel_doi);
        self.mb.cond.notify_one();
        drop(guard);
        self.fetch_info = false;
    }

    fn on_key_event(&mut self, key: KeyEvent) {
        match (key.modifiers, key.code) {
            (_, KeyCode::Esc | KeyCode::Char('q'))
            | (KeyModifiers::CONTROL, KeyCode::Char('c') | KeyCode::Char('C')) => self.quit(),
            (_, KeyCode::Down | KeyCode::Char('j')) => {
                if self.state.selected().unwrap() <= 3 {
                    self.info_text = "... Loading".to_string();
                    self.state.scroll_down_by(1);
                    self.fetch_info = true;
                }
            }
            (_, KeyCode::Up | KeyCode::Char('k')) => {
                self.info_text = "... Loading".to_string();
                self.state.scroll_up_by(1);
                self.fetch_info = true;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    fn quit(&mut self) {
        self.running = false;
    }
}

fn main() -> color_eyre::Result<()> {
    color_eyre::install()?;

    let mb = Mailbox::new();

    let curl_data = Arc::clone(&mb.data);
    let curl_cond = Arc::clone(&mb.cond);
    let curl_output = Arc::clone(&mb.output);
    let curl_bool = Arc::clone(&mb.finished);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        run_bg_cmd(curl_data, curl_cond, curl_output, curl_bool);
    });

    let terminal = ratatui::init();
    let result = App::new(mb).run(terminal);
    ratatui::restore();
    result
}


I know this must be an easy exercise for experienced Rust programmers, but I just don't get it right now...
Still thankful for every help on this!
Newer Edit: even closer
I now run the curl command as spawned process and capture its output. It works fine, expect the case when moving the list steadily but not too fast.
My main function handling the bg-commands in another thread now looks like this:
pub fn run_bg_cmd(
    fetch_item: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>>,
    cond: Arc<Condvar>,
    output_val: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
    finished: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    kill_bool: Arc<AtomicBool>,
) {
    loop {
        let mut request = fetch_item.lock().unwrap();
        while request.is_none() {
            request = cond.wait(request).unwrap();
        }
        let cur_request = request.take().unwrap();

        drop(request);

        let mut bg_cmd = Command::new("curl")
            .arg("-LH")
            .arg("Accept: application/x-bibtex")
            .arg(&cur_request)
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .stderr(Stdio::null())
            .spawn()
            .expect("Not running");

        // let pid = bg_cmd.id();
        loop {
            if kill_bool.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                bg_cmd.kill().unwrap();
                break;
            } else if bg_cmd.wait().unwrap().success() {
                let output = bg_cmd.wait_with_output().unwrap();

                finished.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
                let output = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).to_string();

                let mut output_str = output_val.lock().unwrap();
                *output_str = output;
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

Just need to figure out how to kill a still running process and dismiss its output if a new one is spawned. Tried some approaches with a loop and some AtomicBool's (as above), but that seems to have no effect... Maybe using the PID in some way?

This is an X/Y problem. Instead of invoking curl in a subprocess, you should rather use a native HTTP library with async capability, such as reqwest.

Yes, that would be a great solution. But as mentioned curl is only an example which many *UNIX distros offer. The command I use in my real app is a specific programm of my Linux distro. It has neither a Rust lib, nor a C-lib with an API I can connect to through Rust. Most of its stuff is done in its internal C-Code. Thus, the "best" solution is to run these commands as external processes.

Then I suggest running the subprocesses as tokio tasks and sending their results into an mpsc channel.

I want to get it done using std libs. Of course, tokio is capable of this, but std is either I'm very sure. Before diving deeper into tokio's async stuff, I want to understand the basic way.

See updated answer. I had forgotten that shadowing a MutexGuard doesn't really drop it, so doesn't release the lock.

Ah OK. Again a learning experience for me! Will try it out tomorrow asap! Thanks

Don't spawn a thread for each request, only spawn a single thread at program start, then use a mailbox to send requests to that thread. That way you won't be starting multiple curl requests in parallel and you will only keep the last result.
There's probably a crate implementing a mailbox somewhere, but it's pretty easy to do yourself with a Mutex and a Condvar from std::sync. Something like:
struct Mailbox {
    data: Mutex<Option<String>>;
    cond: Condvar;
}

fn curl_thread (mailbox: Arc<Mailbox>, reply: Sender<String>) {
    loop {
        let mut guard = mailbox.data.lock().unwrap();
        while guard.is_none() { guard = mailbox.cond.wait (guard).unwrap(); }
        let request = guard.take().unwrap(); 
        drop (guard); // Release the lock so that the main thread may proceed while we're running

        todo!("Call curl (or whatever) and send the result using the `reply` channel.");
    }
}

// Send a new request to the `curl_thread`. Note that:
// - This will not interrupt the currently running request if there is one
//   (left as an exercise to the reader)
// - This will only keep at most one pending request, so that if multiple
//   requests are sent while the first one is running, only the last one
//   will be kept.
let guard = mailbox.data.lock().unwrap();
*guard = Some (request);
mailbox.cond.notify_one();
drop (guard);


Thanks for the answer. At the moment, I try to implement your solution. I got it running but it don't work as expected so far... I'll keep trying

Great. Dropping the guard inside the loop solved the problem with the blocked main thread. Now I've to figure out where to call the function which sends the request. Because the TUI is redrawn on any keypress, it redraws the interface before the request is sent. That leads to the problem that it always renders the result from the last item selected before the key was pressed. But thats a typical TUI problem not a thread related...

Thanks to your tipps I'm almost there. The only part I can't get to work is killing outdated bg processes when moving to the next item. Would be happy for a hint, even if you left it as exercise to me ;) I already tried different approaches using AtomicBools, SharedChild and some other stuff... I've updated my current code above

In order to be able to kill outdated processes: 1. use spawn instead of output. 2. use take to take the stdout out of the Child. 3. use kill to stop the child. The stdout will EOF when the child ends (whether naturally or killed).

Don't forget to wait for the child after the EOF, so that the OS will know to cleanup the resources associated with the child.

Spawning, takeing the stdout and killing the Child after wait succeeded is exactly what I did in another approach to this question (which I crossposted on Reddit). The code is here. But the described problem is the same, it still shows the last items result for a few milliseconds when moving the list slowly... But I prefer your approach with the Mutex and Condvar

Killing after wait is useless: when wait returns the child is already dead so killing it does nothing. Note that my comment about spawn/take/kill/wait is meant to allow killing outdated processes when moving to the next item and comes in addition to the Mutex+Condvar solution, not instead of it.

Yes, thats true. I'm still doing a lot trial and error. I now implemented Command with spawn() into the bg thread loop. And collecting the output with wait_with_output() takes care of both: wait for the Child to successfull ends it run and capture the output. Now the only task remaining is to send a kill() signal to the outdated, but still running process if moving the list slowly. Thanks for all your advices. I really learned a lot about using threads/processes etc. in Rust!

wait_with_output takes ownership of the child, so you can no longer kill it…

Haha, OK many drawbacks for me :) I'll try something else. I still don't know how to send the kill() signal from the main thread to the curl loop thread since I can't share the cmd via a struct with an arc between these, but will figure it out somehow...

You don't want to share the Command, but you can certainly put a Mutex<Option<Child>> in the mailbox…

The simple answer (based on the minimal example) is don't do work in the rendering callback. Do behavior type things outside of the callback and only deal with accessing pre-computed (or easy to compute) values in the drawing part of your code.
    fn draw(&mut self, frame: &mut Frame) {
        self.fetch_bibtex();

You'll get a crossterm event for every window size change (multiple per change), key (up/down/repeat), mouse movements (if turned on), focus lost / gained etc. You really really don't want to be sending a curl request every time one of those things happens.
There's lots of things you could do for this, but it's worth taking a step back and being a whole tonne more specific about your task. I suspect it's something like:

When you select a list item, load the info for the selected item by calling a command
When you select another item, ignore the data from the first item coming back (cancel the app perhaps?)
When the app run finishes, fill the data in the details view

Approaches I'd consider:

If you have a limit of number of programs that can run at once, use a semaphore to keep that number under control.
If the data is unchanging, keep a copy of the already loaded data in a cache (e.g. https://crates.io/crates/lru/), and don't load it again.
If you can load a few different pieces of data at once (a full page), do that.
Debounce the list - wait until the list selection has been on the selection for 50-100ms before kicking off the remote calls (helps when scrolling fast)
Consider sending a message over a channel to start the load (mpsc) and receiving (onsehot) responses.
If the time to load is fast enough that you can expect any one load to be human level scale, consider using a watch channel and just loading a single item at a time in a loop in another thread.

while let Some(load_event) = watch_rx.recv() {
    let item = load(..);
    load_event.response.send(item)l
}

Then any changes that happen while loading are just ignored by this thread.

If you can for rust / tui stuff, start with plain threads rather than tokio / async as your default. (Obv. there are lots of reasons that would preclude this, but it's worth saying)
Take ratatui drawing out of the equation, work out how to model your app purely using normal screen output and crossterm inputs. Use tracing statements to understand how and when things happen (this is likely a pain point given the description). Then reincorporate your learning into your app. Ratatui apps really should just be a normal command line app that occasionally converts app state to drawing commands. Don't treat the drawing part as part of your apps behavior, it's mainly just visualization.


Ho, thanks for your comment. You're correct, in my real app I fetch Info's for the selected item. This takes much less time; about 0.3 to 0.5s. Thus, its not really recognizable as CLI command, but in the TUI when scrolling fast, it would block in a single threaded approach. In my solution posted below o also removed the Mutex lock from the drawing function. The draw now just reads a simple Vec and prints what's in it. The vector gets filled by the BG process on demand, if there is no movement for 250ms. I also moved away from async/tokio, now just using simple std::thread

Finally, I found a way to get it work. Thanks to all the advices from @Jmb and some trial and error.
Now after spawning the curl request for the current item, I run an inner loop on matching bg_cmd.try_wait(). If it finish the run successful, the result get assigned to the shared var holding the output. But if the process is still running and another list item is selected, an AtomicBool is set which restarts the main loop of the bg process thread and, thus, the result of the former run is dismissed.
Here is the code. There might be ways to make this more efficient and I would be happy to hear about them. But at least it works now and I nevertheless already learned a lot about multi-threading and bg processes in Rust.
use std::{
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
    process::{Command, Stdio},
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
        Arc, Condvar, Mutex,
    },
    thread,
    time::Duration,
};

use color_eyre::Result;
use crossterm::event::{self, Event, KeyCode, KeyEvent, KeyEventKind, KeyModifiers};
use ratatui::{
    layout::{Constraint, Layout},
    style::{Modifier, Style},
    widgets::{Block, List, ListState, Paragraph},
    DefaultTerminal, Frame,
};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Mailbox {
    finished: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    data: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>>,
    cond: Arc<Condvar>,
    output: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
    kill_proc: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl Mailbox {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            finished: Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
            data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None)),
            cond: Arc::new(Condvar::new()),
            output: Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new())),
            kill_proc: Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
        }
    }
}

pub fn run_bg_cmd(
    fetch_item: Arc<Mutex<Option<String>>>,
    cond: Arc<Condvar>,
    output_val: Arc<Mutex<String>>,
    finished: Arc<AtomicBool>,
    kill_bool: Arc<AtomicBool>,
) {
    // Start the main loop which is running in the background as long as
    // the TUI itself runs
    'main: loop {
        let mut request = fetch_item.lock().unwrap();
        // Wait as long as their is no request sent. If one is send, the
        // Condvar lets the loop run further
        while request.is_none() {
            request = cond.wait(request).unwrap();
        }
        let cur_request = request.take().unwrap();

        // Drop MutexGuard to free up the main thread
        drop(request);

        // Spawn `curl` (or any other bg command) using the sent request as arg.
        // To not flood the TUI I pipe stderr to /dev/null
        let mut bg_cmd = Command::new("curl")
            .arg("-LH")
            .arg("Accept: application/x-bibtex")
            .arg(&cur_request)
            .stdout(Stdio::piped())
            .stderr(Stdio::null())
            .spawn()
            .expect("Not running");

        // Start inner loop to wait for process to end or dismiss the result if
        // next item in the TUI is selected
        'waiting: loop {
            match bg_cmd.try_wait() {
                // If bg process ends with exit code 0, break the inner loop
                // to assign the result to the shared variable.
                // If bg process ends with exit code not 0, restart main loop and
                // drop the result from stdout.
                Ok(Some(status)) => {
                    if status.success() {
                        break 'waiting;
                    } else {
                        continue 'main;
                    }
                }
                // If process is still running and the kill bool was set to true
                // since another item was selected, immiditatley restart the main loop
                // waiting for a new request and, therefore, drop the result
                Ok(None) => {
                    if kill_bool.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
                        continue 'main;
                    }
                }
                // If an error occurs, restart the main loop and drop all output
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Error {e} occured while trying to fetch infors");
                    continue 'main;
                }
            }
        }

        // If waiting loop was broken due to successful bg process, take the output
        // parse it into a string (or whatever) and assign it to the shared var
        // holding the result
        let out = bg_cmd.stdout.take().unwrap();
        let out_reader = BufReader::new(out);

        let mut out_str = String::new();

        for l in out_reader.lines() {
            if let Ok(l) = l {
                out_str.push_str(&l);
            }
        }

        finished.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);

        let mut output_str = output_val.lock().unwrap();
        *output_str = out_str;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct App {
    mb: Mailbox,
    running: bool,
    fetch_info: bool,
    info_text: String,
    list: Vec<String>,
    state: ListState,
}

impl App {
    pub fn new(mb: Mailbox) -> Self {
        Self {
            mb,
            running: false,
            fetch_info: false,
            info_text: String::new(),
            list: vec![
                "http://dx.doi.org/10.1163/9789004524774".into(),
                "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.algal.2015.04.001".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199595006.003.0021".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-4587-2_7".into(),
                "https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199595006.003.0022".into(),
            ],
            state: ListState::default().with_selected(Some(0)),
        }
    }

    pub fn run(mut self, mut terminal: DefaultTerminal) -> Result<()> {
        self.running = true;
        while self.running {
            terminal.draw(|frame| self.draw(frame))?;
            self.handle_crossterm_events()?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn draw(&mut self, frame: &mut Frame) {
        let [left, right] =
            Layout::vertical([Constraint::Fill(1), Constraint::Fill(1)]).areas(frame.area());

        let list = List::new(self.list.clone())
            .block(Block::bordered().title_top("List"))
            .highlight_style(Style::new().add_modifier(Modifier::REVERSED));

        let info = Paragraph::new(self.info_text.as_str())
            .block(Block::bordered().title_top("Bibtex-Style"));

        frame.render_stateful_widget(list, left, &mut self.state);
        frame.render_widget(info, right);
    }

    fn handle_crossterm_events(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
        if event::poll(Duration::from_millis(500))? {
            match event::read()? {
                Event::Key(key) if key.kind == KeyEventKind::Press => self.on_key_event(key),
                Event::Mouse(_) => {}
                Event::Resize(_, _) => {}
                _ => {}
            }
        } else {
            if self.fetch_info {
                self.update_info();
            }
            if self.mb.finished.load(Ordering::Relaxed) == true {
                self.info_text = self.mb.output.lock().unwrap().to_string();
                self.mb.finished.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn update_info(&mut self) {
        // Select current item as request
        let sel_doi = self.list[self.state.selected().unwrap_or(0)].clone();
        let mut guard = self.mb.data.lock().unwrap();
        // Send request to bg loop thread
        *guard = Some(sel_doi);
        // Notify the Condvar to break the hold of bg loop
        self.mb.cond.notify_one();
        drop(guard);
        // Set bool to false, so no further process is started
        self.fetch_info = false;
        // Set kill bool to false to allow bg process to complete
        self.mb.kill_proc.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }

    fn on_key_event(&mut self, key: KeyEvent) {
        match (key.modifiers, key.code) {
            (_, KeyCode::Esc | KeyCode::Char('q'))
            | (KeyModifiers::CONTROL, KeyCode::Char('c') | KeyCode::Char('C')) => self.quit(),
            (_, KeyCode::Down | KeyCode::Char('j')) => {
                if self.state.selected().unwrap() <= 3 {
                    // Set kill bool to true to kill unfinished process from prev item
                    self.mb.kill_proc.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
                    // Set text of info box to "Loading" until bg loop sends result
                    self.info_text = "... Loading".to_string();
                    self.state.scroll_down_by(1);
                    // Set fetch bool to true to start fetching of info after set delay
                    self.fetch_info = true;
                }
            }
            (_, KeyCode::Up | KeyCode::Char('k')) => {
                // Set kill bool to true to kill unfinished process from prev item
                self.mb.kill_proc.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
                // Set text of info box to "Loading" until bg loop sends result
                self.info_text = "... Loading".to_string();
                self.state.scroll_up_by(1);
                // Set fetch bool to true to start fetching of info after set delay
                self.fetch_info = true;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }

    fn quit(&mut self) {
        self.running = false;
    }
}

fn main() -> color_eyre::Result<()> {
    color_eyre::install()?;

    let mb = Mailbox::new();

    let curl_data = Arc::clone(&mb.data);
    let curl_cond = Arc::clone(&mb.cond);
    let curl_output = Arc::clone(&mb.output);
    let curl_bool = Arc::clone(&mb.finished);
    let curl_kill_proc = Arc::clone(&mb.kill_proc);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        run_bg_cmd(curl_data, curl_cond, curl_output, curl_bool, curl_kill_proc);
    });

    let terminal = ratatui::init();
    let result = App::new(mb).run(terminal);
    ratatui::restore();
    result
}

